# "Error: setting an array element with a sequence"

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I am trying to convert Matlab code into Python, but I'm receiving an error when I append zeros in my array.

Matlab Code:

```
N_bits=1e5;
a1=[0,1];
bits=a1(ceil(length(a1)*rand(1,N_bits)));
bits=[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 bits];
```

Python Code:

```
a1=array([0,0,1])
N_bits=1e2
a2=arange(0,2,1)
## Transmitter ##
bits1=ceil(len(a2)*rand(N_bits))
bits=a1[array(bits1,dtype=int)]
bits=array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, bits])
```

I get an error on the last line:

```
Error: 
bits=array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, bits])

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: the line before it should raise an exception, since you don't define a1..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to join the list with the array, so try

```
bits=concatenate(([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], bits))
```

where `concatenate()` is [`numpy.concatenate()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html#numpy.concatenate). You can also use `zeros(8, dtype=int)` in place of the list of zeros (see [`numpy.zeros()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241359/error-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence)).

Unlike in Matlab, something like `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, bits]` in Python creates a list with the initial zeros follows by an *embedded* list.

Matlab:

```
>> x = [1,2,3]

x =

     1     2     3

>> [0,0,x]

ans =

     0     0     1     2     3
```

Python:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>>
>>> [0,0,x]
[0, 0, [1, 2, 3]]
>>> 
>>> [0,0] + x
[0, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Depending on how large 'bits' is you might want to preallocate an array of the appropriate size and then fill it like: `bits = np.zeros(8 + N_bits, dtype='uint8'); bits[8:] = ...`

Comment: @arshajii nope it doesnt work it says     bits=array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]+bits)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (8) (100)

Comment: numpy arrays overload the `+` operator to mean elementwise addition.  To concatenate, use `numpy.concatenate((array1, array2, ...))`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Ack, of course. Must be coffee o'clock for me.